# SECURITY WARNING: Please treat the URL above as you would your password and do not share it with anyone

Tags: facebook, extjs, cordova, sencha-touch, xcode4.3

i develop a sencha touch APP which now i run under XCODE 4.3 project with phonegap.
my app try to connect to the FB with the APPID.
the same code works in my androind application.
but in XCODE i always get that error:

SECURITY WARNING: Please treat the URL above as you would your password and do not share it with anyone.

i already update my FB account application setting and set my XCODe plist as described in other threads.
i also connect only with https.

it happens in that code.

```
initialize: function(appId) {

    this.appId = appId;

    window.fbAsyncInit = Ext.bind(this.onFacebookInit, this);

    (function(d){
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
```

any idea what else i can do?

Eli.

Comment: Why are you using the javascript SDK in a native iOS app? there's a Facebook SDK available for that platform which handles authentication for you

Comment: @Igy, it appears the OP is using PhoneGap/Cordova to wrap a Javascript app for distribution on both the iOS and Android platforms.

Comment: Ah, my mistake, in that case the problem may be out of the developer's control if PhoneGap/Cordova is triggering an auth dialog and trying to extract the access token from the response (the response page for that flow is where the `SECURITY WARNING` message is - that popup usually auto-closes on desktop)